# How can i structure my get requests to MongoDB 3+ using Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Where to call app.get in new MongoDB version 3+ using ExpressJS
I am connected to my MongoDB database and able to write objects,
however, in my server.js I have the following code.

```
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  assert = require('assert');


    const dbName = 'database name';

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://...";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    client.connect(async function (err) {

    assert.equal(null, err);
    if (err) return 1;

    try{

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    } catch(err){
        console.log("error output:" +err);
    }
    client.close();

    });

    app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    var cursor = db.collection('collection-name').find().toArray(function (err, results) {
    res.render('test.ejs', {
        collection-name: results
     });
    });
   });
```

case 1. ReferenceError: db is not defined for above example
case 2. If I put it inside the mongoDB try catch function,   I get back a 404 for test.ejs

Didn't find any accurate examples yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you defined the db variable in client.connect, but you are trying to access the db variable in your GET route. Because of the scope of the variable db variable is not accesible outside of the function it is defined.

The easiest way to share MongoClient is using the expressjs [app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) property.

Basically when you connect to the MongoDB, you save the DB instance globally in app.locals.  And then you can access it in your routes.

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const dbName = "database name";

const uri = "mongodb+srv://...";

MongoClient.connect(
  uri,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }

    console.log("Connected successfully to Mongodb");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    app.locals.db = db;

    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
  }
);

app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const db = req.app.locals.db;

  const users = await db
    .collection("users")
    .find({})
    .toArray();

  res.send(users);
});
```

Comment: Ok one step closer but I get this error now :  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect at selectServers

Comment: @timber535 it looks like you have connection problem,  is it possible to use local mongodb if you have?

Comment: I get an empty object {} from my get request

Comment: @timber535 then is there any problem now?

Comment: MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect at selectServers

Comment: @timber535 I guess it is just a warning in console if so it is not a big issue, if your operations successfully finish.

Comment: Do you have a users collection in your db? If not change the collection name to an existing collection name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203761/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-timber535).

Comment: `app.locals.db = db;` worked for me, I'm new to express + MongoDB, happy to know a better way to achieve this. Thanks.